# Compute mean of vectors in data.table

Tags: r, vector, data.table

I am implementing k-Means. This is my main datastructures:

dt1 is a Data.table with{Filename,featureVector,GroupItBelongsTo}

```
dt1<- data.table(Filename=files[1:limit],Vector=list(),G=-1)
setkey(dt1,Filename)
```

featureVector is a list. It has words associated with occurance, I am adding the occurance to each word using this line:

```
featureVector[[item]] <- emaildt[email==item]$N
```

A typical excerpt from my console when I call `dt1` is.

```
   Filename                          Vector          G
1: 000057219a473629b53d33cfedef590f.txt 1,1,1,1,1,1, 3
2: 00007afb5a5e467a39e517ae87e7fad5.txt 0,0,0,0,0,0, 3
3: 000946d248fdb1d5d05c59a91b00e8f2.txt 0,0,0,0,0,0, 3
4: 000bea8dc6f716a2cac6f25bdbe09073.txt 0,0,0,0,0,0, 3
```

I now want to compute new centroids for each group number. **Meaning I want to sum all vector positions at position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NQye.png) with each other, [2] etc.. until the end, and after that - average them all.**

Example: v1=[1,1,1], v2=[2,2,2],I would expect the centroid to be = c1=[1,5;1,5;1,5]

I tried to do: sapply(dt1[tt]$Vector,mean) (also tried with "sum") and it sums and "means" row-wise(inside each vector), not column wise(each n-th component) like I would like it to do.

How to do it?

====Update, answering a question in comments====

```
> head(dt1)

       Filename                         Vector       G
1: 000057219a473629b53d33cfedef590f.txt 1,1,1,1,1,1, 1
2: 00007afb5a5e467a39e517ae87e7fad5.txt 0,0,0,0,0,0, 1
3: 000946d248fdb1d5d05c59a91b00e8f2.txt 0,0,0,0,0,0, 3
4: 000bea8dc6f716a2cac6f25bdbe09073.txt 0,0,0,0,0,0, 4
5: 000fcfac9e0a468a27b5e2ad0f78d842.txt 0,0,0,0,0,0, 1
6: 00166a4964d6c939f8f62280b85e706d.txt 0,0,0,1,0,0, 1
> class(dt1)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
>
```

Typing `dt1$Vector` gives(I only copied a small sample, it has many more words but they all look the same):

```
[[1]]
homosexuality       articles         church         people       interest 
         1              1              1              1              1 
    thread          email           send        warning          worth 
         1              1              1              1              1
```

And here is the class() output

```
> class(dt1$Vector)
[1] "list"
```

Screenshots when typing:

```
 A<-as.matrix(t(as.data.frame(dt1$Vector)))
```

[image: Result of the head of (A), where A is as.matrix(t(as.data.frame(dt1$Vector)))]

Result of `class(dt1$Vector[[1]])`:

```
[1] "numeric"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, (the obligatory) you might consider using the R function `kmeans` to do your k-means clustering.  If you prefer to roll your own, you can easily compute centroids of a data table as follows.  First, I'll build some random data that looks like yours:

```
> set.seed(123)
> dt<-data.table(name=LETTERS[1:20],replicate(5,sample(0:4,20,T)),G=sample(3,20,T))
> head(dt)
   name V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 G
1:    A  1  4  0  3  1 2
2:    B  3  3  2  0  3 1
3:    C  2  3  2  1  2 2
4:    D  4  4  1  1  3 3
5:    E  4  3  0  4  0 2
6:    F  0  3  0  2  2 3
```

The centroids can be computed in one line:

```
> dt[,lapply(.SD[,-1],mean),by=G]
   G       V1       V2   V3       V4       V5
1: 2 2.375000 2.250000 1.25 2.125000 2.250000
2: 1 2.800000 2.400000 2.40 1.800000 1.400000
3: 3 1.714286 2.428571 1.00 2.142857 1.857143
```

If you're going to do this, you might want to drop the names from the data table (temporarily), in which case you can just do:

```
> dt2<-copy(dt)
> dt2$name<-NULL
> dt2[,lapply(.SD,mean),by=G]
   G       V1       V2   V3       V4       V5
1: 2 2.375000 2.250000 1.25 2.125000 2.250000
2: 1 2.800000 2.400000 2.40 1.800000 1.400000
3: 3 1.714286 2.428571 1.00 2.142857 1.857143
```

Edit:  a better way to do this, suggested by @Roland, is to use `.SDcols`:

```
dt[,lapply(.SD,mean),by=G,.SDcols=2:6]
```

Comment: You might be interested in `.SDcols`.

Comment: It seems that you have 6 columns, whereas I have only 3, and the middle column contains a list() of elements being my vector. How do I do in my case ? Can I transform it somehow nicely to a matrix and then do it, or is there a direct way ?

Comment: @Roland Thanks, that is indeed better.

Comment: @user2827159 You want to avoid having lists of vectors in a data table if possible.  There might be a way to take the means directly, but you what you really want to do is get the data into matrix form.  The best thing to do is to change the code that you use to build the dataset.  If you don't want to do that, the command `dt2<-data.table(dt1,as.matrix(t(as.data.frame(dt1$features))))[,features:=NULL]` should build a new data frame that splits the features vector into separate columns.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work. I removed the []-parenthesis at the end, I get then a matrix of lists and I am still unable to apply a function generating the means the way I want(it performs it list-wise, not element-wise)

Comment: Can you post the output of `head(dt1$features)` and `class(dt1$features)`?

Comment: I updated the question with the output of your questions. I would be really thankful for helping me with this :-).

Comment: What happens when you type `as.matrix(t(as.data.frame(dt1$Vector)))`?  Also, what is `class(dt$Vector[[1]])`?

Comment: Updated the thread again. Is there a better way of communicating such things through stackoverflow? :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39152/discussion-between-mrip-and-user2827159)